# how to make ordinary system/server as proxy server

Tags: proxy

Can we make an ordinary server as a proxy server?

If suppose i have 10 proxy servers and 1 httprequest, is it possible to forward the request via 10 proxy servers?

Please answer my above two questions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can we make an ordinary server as a proxy server?
Do you mean can a ordinary hardware server be used as a proxy, yes use [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or even just [IPTables](http://www.netfilter.org/).

If you mean can an ordinary HttpServer can be used as a proxy?
Yes, you use [continuations](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Continuations) to suspend the request and then make a new request from the first server. When the you get the result you resume the continuation and return the response to the user. Could you tell use the use case which would help me understand the question better.